# Optimal way to find number of operation required to convert all K numbers to lie in the range [L,R] (i.e. L≤x≤R)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, combinatorics

> I am solving this question which requires some optimized techniques to
>   solve it. I can think of  the brute force method only which requires
>   combinatorics.
>
> Given an array A consisting of n integers. We call an integer "good"
>   if it lies in the range [L,R] (i.e. L≤x≤R). We need to make sure if we
>   pick up any K integers from the array at least one of them should be a
>   good integer.
>
> For achieving this, in a single operation, we are  allowed to
>   increase/decrease any element of the array by one.
>
> What will be the minimum number of operations we will need for a
>   fixed k?"
>
> i.e k=1 to n.

```
input:
L  R
1  2

A=[ 1 3 3 ]

output:
for k=1 : 2 
for k=2 : 1
for k=3 : 0
```

> For k=1, you have to convert both the 3s into 2s to make sure that if
>   you select any one of the 3 integers, the selected integer is good.
>
> For k=2, one of the possible ways is to convert one of the 3s into 2.
>
> For k=3, no operation is needed as 1 is a good integer.

Comment: what is the size of the input array?

Comment: Hint ! Preprocess using DP

Comment: @PhamTrung n≤10^5 and A[i]≤10^9..

Comment: @therealprashant initially I thought about DP but was not able to come up with an structure. what according to you can be the starting point for DP.?

Comment: @PhamTrung  I have written in question its k= 1 to N

Comment: So we will need to calculate all results for `k` from 1 to N? or just one value of `k`?

Comment: @PhamTrung  for each value of K there should be a result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As burnpanck has explained in his answer, to make sure that when you pick any k elements in the array, and at least one of them is in range [L,R], we need to make sure that there are at least `n - k + 1` numbers in range [L,R] in the array.

So, first , for each element, we calculate the cost to make this element be a `valid` element (which is in range [L,R]) and store those cost in an array `cost`.

We notice that:

- For k = 1, the minimum cost is the sum of array `cost`.
- For k = 2, the minimum cost is the sum of `cost`, minus the largest element.
- For k = 3, the minimum cost is the sum of `cost`, minus two largest elements.

  ...

So, we need to have a `prefixSum` array, which ith position is the sum of **sorted** `cost` array from 0 to ith.

After calculate prefixSum, we can answer result for each k in O(1)

So here is the algo in Java, notice the time complexity is **O(n logn)**:

```
int[]cost = new int[n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cost[i] = //Calculate min cost for element i
Arrays.sort(cost);
int[]prefix = new int[n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   prefix[i] = cost[i] + (i > 0 ? prefix[i - 1] : 0);

for(int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
   System.out.println("Result for k = " + (n - i) + " is " + prefix[i]);
```

Comment: I understood it ,just a bit clarification why this -- "For k = 2, the minimum cost is the sum of cost, minus the largest element.". I mean why minus largest element. what is the relation I am not able to think of it. Thanks

Comment: @Ashish because, when k = 2, we need to make all elements in the array to become valid element, except one element, and we can choose that element. So to get minimum cost, wee need to choose the element that has largest cost.

Comment: Finally .... Thanks for bearing all those questions.... Now I'm thinking how come  i was missing that point... but again all question looks easy once you know the solution... :)

Comment: @Ashish Glad this help  :), can you make this as accepted if it answered your question?

Answer (score 1):

To be sure that from picking k elements will give at least one valid means you should have not more than k-1 invalid in your set. You therefore need to find the shortest way to make enough elements valid. This I would do as follows: In a single pass, generate a map that counts how many elements are in the set that need $n$ operations to be made valid. Then, you clearly want to take those elements that need the least operations, so take the required number of elements in ascending order of required number of operations, and sum the number of operations.

In python:

```
def min_ops(L,R,A_set):
    n_ops = dict()  # create an empty mapping
    for a in A_set:   # loop over all a in the set A_set
        n = max(0,max(a-R,L-a))  # the number of operations requied to make a valid
        n_ops[n] = n_ops.get(n,0) + 1  # in the mapping, increment the element keyed by *n* by ones. If it does not exist yet, assume it was 0.
    allret = []   # create a new list to hold the result for all k
    for k in range(1,len(A_set)+1):  # iterate over all k in the range [1,N+1) == [1,N]
        n_good_required = len(A_set) - k + 1
        ret = 0
        # iterator over all pairs of keys,values from the mapping, sorted by key.
        # The key is the number of ops required, the value the number of elements available
        for n,nel in sorted(n_ops.items()):   
            if n_good_required:
               return ret
            ret += n * min(nel,n_good_required)
            n_good_required -= nel
        allret.append(ret)  # append the answer for this k to the result list
    return allret
```

As an example:

```
A_set = [1,3,3,6,8,5,4,7]
L,R = 4,6
```

For each A, we find how many operations we need to make it valid:

```
n = [3,1,1,0,2,0,0,1]
```

(i.e. 1 needs 3 steps, 3 needs one, and so on)
Then we count them:

```
n_ops = {
    0: 3,   # we already have three valid elements
    1: 3,   # three elements that require one op
    2: 1,
    3: 1,   # and finally one that requires 3 ops
}
```

Now, for each k, we find out how many valid elements we need in the set,
e.g. for k = 4, we need at most 3 invalid in the set of 8, so we need 5 valid ones.

Thus:

```
ret = 0
n_good_requied = 5
with n=0, we have 3 so take all of them
ret = 0
n_good_required = 2
with n=1, we have 3, but we need just two, so take those
ret = 2
we're finished
```

Comment: can you give a little more insight. may be a demonstration with example will do. thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with with python. Can you put comments aside your code so that its easier for everyone not knowing python to get you points clearly.

Comment: And it will we nice if you can demonstrate your code with above example and how its getting right answer. Thanks

Comment: n_ops = {
    0: 3,   # we already have three valid elements
    1: 3,   # three elements that require one op
    2: 1,
    3: 1,   # and finally one that requires 3 ops
}  What are the 3 elements that require 1 operation. I can only see one element i.e 3

Comment: let say we have k=4 as per your question and we choose 1,3,3,6 from array. Then our answer should be 5.(3 op for 1 and 1 each for 3). How your algo cope with it.or I am not getting something?

Comment: I understood the initial question in the same way burnpanck did: It was never specified that the K integers that you pick have to be next to each other in the initial array. Thus you made sure to always obtain at least one good integer for an arbitrary pick if and only if you have at most k-1 "bad" integers left in your array. If this is not intended, please edit the question to clarify this :)

Comment: @HW I have written it already that we can pick "any" K numbers and it doesn't have to to be contiguous.

Comment: In that case, i agree with burnpancks solution.

Comment: The solution currently is O(N^2) which is not optimal: The inner nested for-loop repeatedly does the same thing. Reversing the outer loop direction, and for each lower k one can continue from the result of higher k, and the solution becomes O(N log N) (due to the sorting of the initial map).